# Figwheel environment variables

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent, figwheel

I understand Figwheel allows me to specify different builds. (Perhaps another way to think of them is as environments?)

Based on the build/environment, I may require a different behavior in my code. For example, when in dev, I connect to a certain API endpoint, and in prod it's a different endpoint. Ideally, I would like some way (presumably this belongs in project.clj) of specifying environment specific variables, and then access them in my cljs code.

Is there a mechanism to do this?

I'm picturing something like this:

```
:cljsbuild {
    :builds [{:id "dev"
              :source-paths ["src"]
              :figwheel true
              :env-variables {foo "bar"
                              bar "foo"} ; <-------
              :compiler {:main hello-seymore.core 
                         :asset-path "cljs/out"
                         :output-to  "resources/public/cljs/main.js"
                         :output-dir "resources/public/cljs/out"} 
             }
             {:id "prod"
              :env-variables {foo "different value for foo"
                              bar "different value for bar"}}] ; <-------
              ; etc
   }
```

And then in my cljs code I would like to access them somehow. If it matters, I am running a Reagent project.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is via [`closure-defines`](https://clojurescript.org/reference/compiler-options#closure-defines).

E.g. in your `project.clj`:

```
:cljsbuild { ; ...
            :builds [{:id "min"
                      ;;; XXX: map with your values
                      :compiler {:closure-defines {"example.core.version" ~version}
                                 ; ...
```

`version` is a def in my project here.  So you can adjust that to reading an env-var etc.

```
(def version
  (->
    (clojure.java.shell/sh "git" "describe" "--always")
    :out
    clojure.string/trim))
```

Then in your `example.core` ns:

```
(goog-define version "dev")
```

And then use it like a regular `def`-ed thing.

Comment: Another option could be macros.  Since they are clojure code, that run while you build, they should be able to pick up things from your build env.

Comment: I'm confused as to how to access this later. If in `:compiler` I set my `:closure-defines` to `{"my-project.core.foo" "bar"}`, how do I access `foo` later in my project?

Comment: @weltschmerz add `(good-define foo "some default")` in your `my-project.core` ns

Comment: Also note that, while macros can consume environment variables and generate code accordingly, `:closure-defines` is preferable as this produces code that is cache-friendly. For example, see the discussion of macros in https://clojurescript.org/news/2018-03-28-shared-aot-cache

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've already read all about [lein profiles](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md). If you haven't seen it yet, be sure to check out [Dynamic Eval](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md#dynamic-eval) in lein:

```
{:user {:compile-path  #=(eval (System/getenv "ci.compile-path" )),
        :target-path   #=(eval (System/getenv "ci.target-path"  )) }}
```

You could then use the dynamically read information to set a different `:main`, or a different `:source-paths` to pull in code with different constants.

Of course, don't forget to review all of [the compiler options](https://clojurescript.org/reference/compiler-options).